# Ways to invoke a Windows application through a http URL?

Tags: windows, wcf, http

I have a Windows desktop application that I'd like users to be able to invoke through a URL. The main idea is that they can launch the installed app with certain command-line parameters through, say, a link in their email. Additionally, an *optimal* implementation would handle the situation where the user doesn't *already* have the app installed, so that they fall-through to a download link. (Likely the download location will be a machine on the users network, not necessarily a web address).

At the risk of making this an X and Y problem here's what I've considered:

To just invoke an already-installed application, I've considered implementing a custom protocol handler ([msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), but that would give them a URL like **myapp://whatever?blar=123**. If they don't already have the application installed, this url won't work, and they won't be redirected to download the application.

I've considered a WCF REST listener service that runs in the background, so the links can use http and be formulated like http://some-network-machine/whatever?blar=123, where if the app is installed, it would trap the call and launch the application, and if it's not installed, the call will fall through to "some-network-machine" which will serve up a download page. I'm only just learning WCF, so I don't know if this is possible (handling calls intended for a different machine)?

**To summarize:** I'd like users to be able to invoke my application through a URL, and if the application isn't already installed, to have them directed to a download page for the application. Any thoughts, expertise or similar experiences are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it how Spotify does it.

(Spotify is a free music streaming service mainly in Europe at the moment: http://www.spotify.com should you not have heard of it. It has quite a few social / sharing features)

For example, you can copy and share HTTP links such as

http://open.spotify.com/track/6DHrdGLyfF01vz17Bl2O7O

Which then try and open the `spotify:track:6DHrdGLyfF01vz17Bl2O7O` link. Should you not have the application installed it will fail, and you can use the information on that page to install the application.

Comment: This is an interesting approach and very well may be what I ultimately go with. The downside of course is that it requires an additional step of opening the browser, even if they *do* have the application already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Considering, your web application is aware of the application startup exe file location,
You can execute exe on client side only through javascript.

Try this:- `http://forums.asp.net/t/1643217.aspx/1?How+to+open+exe+program+which+installed+on+client+machine+asp+net+C+`

```
http://forums.asp.net/t/1124574.aspx
```

Comment: Installation location on the users machine is never a sure thing (Program Files vs. Program Files (x86), for example). Otherwise this answer isn't *too* different from Dotmister's answer above, other than his answer presumes a custom protocol to have been registered on the user's machine (i.e. myapp://).